# Paypal Adaptive Ipn

Tags: php, paypal-ipn

I have sending this in my request parameters and I need to get the custom field as response through the IPN but it will not work.

```
$nvpStr='&actionType=PAY_PRIMARY'
        .'&clientDetails.applicationId=APP-80W284485P519543T'
        .'&currencyCode=USD'
        .'&feesPayer=EACHRECEIVER'
        .'&receiverList.receiver(0).amount='.$amount
        .'&receiverList.receiver(0).email=mehar_singh-facilitator@rvtechnologies.info'
        .'&receiverList.receiver(0).primary=true'
        .'&receiverList.receiver(1).amount='.$ownerAmount
        .'&receiverList.receiver(1).email=kshitizagrawal5-facilitator@gmail.com'
        .'&requestEnvelope.errorLanguage=en_US'                       .'&clientDetails.deviceId='.urlencode(stripslashes($custom))
        .'&returnUrl='.$return_url
        .'&cancelUrl='.$cancel_url
        .'&ipnNotificationUrl='.$notify_url                            .'&receiverOptions[0].invoiceData.item[0].number='.urlencode(stripslashes($item_number))                           .'&receiverOptions[0].invoiceData.item[0].name='.urlencode(stripslashes($item_name))
        .'&custom='.$custom;
```

I need this &custom parameter to be sent by Ipn. I get the response like:
first_name               test
payer_id                 9FVAGLE995JH2
receiver_id              WLCEU3Y5FGCUE
item_number
payment_status           Completed
payment_fee              0.10
mc_fee                   0.10
mc_gross                 2.10
custom
charset                  windows-1252
notify_version           3.8
ipn_track_id             e519d69aeb7b.

I need this custom variable to be filled. Please let me know the request parameter for this custom variable without using the hidden form or any other parameter that I will used to send my custom data and it is returned by Ipn.